# Help to find spherical Line

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

> What is the spherical line through the points $(0,-1,0)$ and $\left(0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$?

I solved:

$G = \{(x,y,z)\in S^2 \mid \exists\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, ax+by+cz = 0\}$

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a(0)+ b(\frac{1}{2})+ c(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})=0\\ 
a(0)-b+c(0)=0
\end{matrix}\right.$

=> $\left\{\begin{matrix}
b+ (\sqrt{3})c=0\\ 
-b=0
\end{matrix}\right.$

.

.

.

I think my solution is wrong.

Please help me to solve this question.

Comment: Hint: These points both lie on a circle in the y-z plane. What does a line look like on a sphere?

Comment: @amWhy: you are welcome -<;@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quite on the right track, here. The way you've written it $G$ is all of $S^2$, since if we simply take $a=b=c=0,$ then $ax+by+cz=0.$ What you want is to find some $a,b,c\in\Bbb R$ not all zero such that the set $$\{(x,y,z)\in S^2\mid ax+by+cz=0\}$$ contains your two points.

You're doing fine solving the system, so far. From $-b=0$ we conclude that $b=0$, whence $0=b+c\sqrt3=c\sqrt3,$ and so $c=0$. Now $a$ is a free variable of the system, but since $b=c=0$, then we must take $a\ne0$. Our set then becomes $$\{(x,y,z)\in S^2\mid ax=0\},$$ or equivalently $$\{(x,y,z)\in S^2\mid x=0\}$$ (since $a\ne0$).

Comment: +Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: @flashdesign2550: It is really a good answer.

Comment: @Babak S.:yes.Precisely.Thanks so much.